# Should I force myself to do a thing which my mind does not believe?

Tags: behavior

It's really not rational for me to do a thing while my mind does not believe it. What does Islam expect from me when it says something is **sin** but my mind does not believe that it's a sin?

Does it expect from me to force myself?

While I myself would like to try that sin to see the results because that sin is not harmful for anyone in my mind's idea so it's not a sin really. I believe forcing myself does not make any practical advantage for me and causes that I could not find out if it's really sin or not in whole of my life! what's the solution?

Comment: try it than and see the resaults on Yawmul Qiama. Really you should think more about your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure what you think is a sin in Islam? Is it addressed in Quran/hadith or is it just an interpretation of somebody? If it is clearly addressed in Quran/hadith, then unless you believe it is a sin you won't be a Mumin. If that is the case, you should force yourself to believe it is a sin and ask the help of Allah. And most importantly, you must not discuss if some specific thing (which is declared sin in Quran/hadith) is a sin or not with other people. If you do so, it won't take long before you lose the title 'Muslim'.

If we had infinite knowledge, we could decide what is right and what is wrong ourselves. But, we don't and we won't: *"Knower of the unseen, and He does not disclose His unseen to anyone"* (72:26). This is why we surrender; He always knows better.

Comment: I don't know enough Hadith but it is clearly addressed in Quran in only a few places. Rather than the sin Sherk, It says slightly to do not that but does not say strongly that if you do you'll be in fire for everytime! I understand your answer but I can not force myself for whole of my life, it's really harmful!

Comment: So why Quran says افلا تعقلون (why you do not think?) why I should think while I should force myself?

Comment: @YasserZamani If you cannot, then at least admit you are committing a sin by doing that. There is a huge difference between the two. Most Muslims are sinners, but they are Muslims because they believe they are sinners and turn to God for forgiveness.

Comment: @YasserZamani You should think about the signs of God and implications of your actions, but not about the rules of God. This is why they are called rules.

Comment: *"...you must not discuss if some specific thing (which is declared sin in Quran/hadith) is a sin or not with other people."* Why would there be anything wrong with *discussing* it? Does this make all [tag:sin-or-not] questions illegal?

Comment: @muntoo when Allah or His messenger says something, it is final. You may only discuss about how to apply it, but not about the saying/order itself.

Answer (score 2):

Salaam,

The meaning of Islam is "submission". You submit yourself (your will, judgement, desires..etc) to the Will of GOD, in return you get the reward. 
It turns out that the orders of God are good for us, but that is not the main reason to obey them. We do not avoid pork meat because it is good for our health, we do it only because we are ordered to. This is rock solid faith. Since GOD is all merciful, it turns out that what is forbidden is bad for us.
verses do exist for proof:

chapter 2, verse 285:
The Messenger has believed in what was revealed to him from his Lord, and [so have] the believers. All of them have believed in Allah and His angels and His books and His messengers, [saying], "We make no distinction between any of His messengers." And they say, "**We hear and we obey.** [We seek] Your forgiveness, our Lord, and to You is the [final] destination

chapter 7, verse 157:
Those who follow the Messenger, the unlettered prophet, whom they find written in what they have of the Torah and the Gospel, who enjoins upon them what is right and forbids them what is wrong and **makes lawful for them the good things and prohibits for them the evil** and relieves them of their burden and the shackles which were upon them. So they who have believed in him, honored him, supported him and followed the light which was sent down with him - it is those who will be the successful.

Comment: So why Quran says افلا تعقلون (why you do not think?) why I should think while I should force myself?

Comment: @YasserZamani, you are right. ALLAH asks us to think. But before that he gives us the great knowledge of what is right and what is wrong: the Qur'an and Hadith. Use this knowledge to think what is right and what is wrong, don't let your ego decide. But still Allah has set us free on earth. We can first experiment and maybe then Allah will give us Hidayah. But we never know how much time we have before death, we have to complete our experiments and build up our imaan before it comes.

Answer (score 2):

In your comments of some of the given answers here you always use

> افلا تعقلون

as an argument, which seems to support your claim. After checking the Verses where this statement is quoted i came to the following explanation: It only means "Then will you not reason?" or "Don't you understand?" which is only a statement after Allah gave an explanation why something was a sin, not an order to think in general as you seem to have understood it: It has more to be understood as an order to make the right decision or implication of the given facts! A better argument -based on the Quran- in my opinion would be using expressions where following others blindly is declared as wrong ... maybe I may find better examples later! (This [article in Arabic](http://www.farajat.net/ar/35331) shows a couple of useful Verses)

**Should we follow blindly or use our mind?**

Battle of Karabala quoted a helpful Verse from the [Quran](http://legacy.quran.com/21/7). Which I would interpret as follows Allah and his Prophet (Peace be upon him) have shown us the right path and defined it for us. We can take it as is or try to understand it, for example by checking whether they go ahead with the [goals of shari'a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maqasid) مقاصد الشريعة and

> there are five fundamental goals these are the preservation of:
>
> - Religion / Faith (din)
> - Life (nafs)
> - Lineage / Progeny (nasl)
> - Intellect (‘aql)
> - Property / Wealth (mal)

Now after this whether you commit a sin or not is your own decision! As if you checked it and still had doubts then asked a scholar as indicated by the Verse (21:7) and your doubts didn't vanish you still can try it!

Doubting is an adapted philosophy of Imam [al-Ghazali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Ghazali#Incoherence_of_the_Philosophers) some scholars accuse  [Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes) of plagiarism because his statement *Cogito ergo sum* or methodological skepticism seems to have its origin in al-Ghazali's statement which can be translated as "I doubt then I exist". And it's even said that Descartes had some books of him in his private library!

**On the relation between Iman and committing a sin**

In addition I would add the following statement of a [Hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6810) which you may find in Sahih al-Bukhari and all the other six major Sunni Hadith Collections (Sahih Muslim, Sunan abi Dawod, Sunan ibn Majah, Sunan a-Nasa-i and Jami' at-Tirmidhi)

> "The one who commits an illegal sexual intercourse is not a believer
> at the time of committing illegal sexual intercourse and a thief is
> not a believer at the time of committing theft and a drinker of
> alcoholic drink is not a believer at the time of drinking. Yet, (the
> gate of) repentance is open thereafter."

This statement seems to indicate that committing a sin is in first place a sign of weakness in the faith of a believer. This weakness can be temporary. Scholars interpret it as follows

> that a believer doesn't commit a sin if his faith/belief is complete
> ... this is supported by an other [Hadith](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/44) (in Sahih al-Bukhari
> -here [an other Version](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/113)- and Sahih Muslim and other Collections) on the authority of abu Dharr al-Ghafari (May Allah be pleased with
> him). ... even if scholars are in consensus that this sins are major
> sins, but nobody would be called a disbeliever if committing them ...
> but believers with a lack of Iman (faith) ... if they repent their
> punishment will disperse and if they died without repentance, Allah
> may forgive them and let them enter paradise or he may punish them and
> later let them enter paradise!
>
> (This is taken from Imam an-Nawawi's al-Majmo' according this [Arabic Fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/50018))

So you can use your mind to try to understand why Allah has declared something as sin, I would even say you should, as some scholars used to say Allah loves/likes being worshiped by knowledge (not blindly followed). If you have strong Iman you may find out that these sins are bad and things which you shouldn't do!

**There's no enforcement -at least a bit of- doubt is allowed**

And finally if you read ([2:256-260](http://legacy.quran.com/2/256-260)) you may find statements like

> There shall be no compulsion in [acceptance of] the religion. The
> right course has become clear from the wrong. ...

and how Allah dealt with doubtful people.

And Allah knows best!

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed nafs (evil ego) and the shaitaan (satan) that drives us to try something forbidden. The very name of the religion **"ISLAM"** means **submission to Allah.** No person who is **totally submitted to Allah** will let his **nafs arouse him.** He would **never try anything that is forbidden** because he **loves and fears Allah.** Let us be among them. Let us be **slaves of Allah,** not **slaves** of **nafs** and **Shaitaan.** Unless we try our best to keep away from the forbidden, we are not on the right path.

Comment: So why Quran says افلا تعقلون (why you do not think?) why I should think while I should force myself?

Comment: @YasserZamani, you are right. ALLAH asks us to think. But before that he gives us the great knowledge of what is right and what is wrong: the Qur'an and Hadith. Use this knowledge to think what is right and what is wrong, don't let your ego decide. But still Allah has set us free on earth. We can first experiment and maybe then Allah will give us Hidayah. But we never know how much time we have before death, we have to complete our experiments and build up our imaan before it comes.

Answer (score 0):

All other questions seem to miss the mark, so I will write this answer even though it is very late.

##### Sins

A sin is defined as something Allah has forbidden and something we are liable to be punished by Him in the hereafter for. Whether it is (physically) harmful or not is often irrelevant. Even though sins are often harmful, this is a correlation rather than a causation.

So, how will you "find out if it's really sin or not"? Do you get revelation from Allah to decide if something is a sin?

##### Harm

At most, you can check if something is harmful (and even that with very limited perspective) while Allah's perspective is complete and perfect. However, as explained above, the way of deciding whether something is a sin is not whether one finds it harmful, but whether God forbade that thing.

##### أَفَلَا تَعْقِلُونَ

The verses of أَفَلَا تَعْقِلُونَ ("So, will you not think?") are clear proof that we need to use our reasoning to figure out things. So, to figure out if something is a sin, we are to use our reasoning to figure out whether God revealed this book which claims it is a sin. That can be done through a variety of means including studying the proofs of prophethood and so on.

Islam is a religion of reasoning, not one of illogical things. The issue, thus, is not in your use of reasoning, but your misunderstanding of what constitutes a sin in the first place. A sin is what you will be liable to be punished by God for.

Do you want to be punished? Go ahead and do the sin. Do you not want to be punished? Stay away from it. Do you want to check if something is a sin with your reasoning? Go study whether the book it is written in or the source it came from is truly from God and whether God has truly declared it forbidden and sinful.

Answer (score -1):

If you are a Muslim you should not disobey what is strictly stated in Quran (because you DO believe in Quran) but in contrary outside Quran you should not obey anything that your mind dones not believe.

> وَلَا تَقْفُ مَا لَيْسَ لَكَ بِهِ عِلْمٌ إِنَّ السَّمْعَ وَالْبَصَرَ
>   وَالْفُؤَادَ كُلُّ أُولَٰئِكَ كَانَ عَنْهُ مَسْئُولًا ﴿الإسراء: ٣٦﴾
>
> And pursue not that thou hast no knowledge of; the hearing, the sight,
>   the heart -- all of those shall be questioned of.

Comment: So why Quran says افلا تعقلون (why you do not think?) why I should think while I should force myself?

Answer (score -1):

No
If Islam is illogical so it is not a true religion.
If Islam is a true religion so should be logical.
If you do not know you should ask "the people of Message" which are Ahl Bayt:

فَاسْأَلُوا أَهْلَ الذِّكْرِ إِن كُنتُمْ لَا تَعْلَمُونَ [٢١:٧]
[en.sahih] ... so ask the people of the message if you do not know. ‌[21:7]

Indeed they should reply I do not know. Because Allah said ask them. So they should be representative of God.
look at history of Islam who never said I do not know.

you you heard an illogical answer you should know that answer is from an false sect of Islam.
prophet said:
کل ما حکم به العقل حکم بعه الشرع و کل ما حکم به الشرع حکم به الغقل

Anything is commanded by reasoning is commanded by religion and anything is commanded by religion is commanded by reasoning.

Comment: +1 I knew and I asked them (Marjae/Reference) before. They said that I should force myself! I dont know how they can force themselves to being which just God says. While I think `A GOD`, should be potential enough to allow me to do what I think it's not false but rescue me after if it was false truly; because I'll do this for whom I love and God says that he's most merciful!