# Why can't I find proof for Islam that I can see for myself?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, miracles

Before I start, please note that I'm a Muslim and have always been one. I pray regularly without missing a single Salah. 
I'm not a rebellious person who's just trying to prove islam wrong either. And I try my best to not be ignorant. It's not like this is a new question in my head. I've had this question for years, but it never affected my prayers or kept me from believing. Perhaps because I never answered it and kept postponing it for a later time, or perhaps because I completely ignored it and kept worshipping Allah nonetheless. I've been a practising muslim for years. But recent events in my life have caused me to not be able to ignore this question. And why wouldn't they?

I mean, Islam unquestionably has a huge impact on my life. Be it the way I dress, the way I interact with people, the way I earn etc. I'm supposed to keep myself from doing so many things, restrict my self in so many ways that I wouldn't have to otherwise. I'm supposed to do all that, and I can't even get a single clear proof of it being true? I'm supposed to do all that on just blind faith?

Sure, you have "clear proofs" like 1)the Quran being miraculous in it's linguistic nature  2) it being unchanged and unedited for 1400 years  3) It made true prophecies and of course,  4) the scientific miracles (let's not get into that).

But none of those are proofs FOR ME. I mean, they might be true, but how am **I** supposed to know? I'm not an arab to see the Quran's linguistic miracle. Is that only for the Arabs to see? What about the rest of the world? Are we literally just supposed to take their word for it? 
They say no human has been able to beat it. Well that might be, but even if that's the case, how is it miraculous? That just makes it a fine peace of unbeaten work, not a miracle. Isn't a miracle something that when seen, you are sure it's a miracle?
And regarding the Quran being unchanged for 1400 years and it making prophecies, I wasn't there to see that. All I've seen is people tell me stories. That's no proof for me. I've just been around for 20 years. How can I judge the legitimacy of a 1400 year old book and it's prophecies? Get to know about them from other people who haven't seen anything themselves either?

See that's the thing. Those "countless clear proofs" I have are just words from other people. The Hadith that describe the prophet and his miracles, how can we be sure about them?

When I see other people, even Muslims sometimes, who don't really care about religion.... I've come to realize that they do so not because they're arrogant. It's that they just can't know if it really is true. The Quran and Hadith mention so many ways in which the disbelievers are going to be tormented for disbelieving, but here's the thing: Is god going to punish us if we disbelieve when we just couldn't have known if Islam even was his religion? I mean no one would want to be tormented forever whatever the cost in this world. The disbelievers do what they do not because they aren't afraid of God or anything (why would anyone be not afraid of God), they do it just because they have no evidence for believing.

I'm in no way saying that Islam is false, I'm just saying that I don't have any proof to back my beliefs up with. It's just blind faith for me. Of course I could rationalize Islam to myself, but rationalization can only go so far. In the end you could rationalize most beliefs to yourself if you WANTED them to be the truth. I don't want that.

It's not like I just want to be happy and have a headache-less life. I really don't care about how happy I am in this world. I don't really care about what I can or cannot have as long as I'm sure about my beliefs. But leaving so many pleasures and opportunities just for something **that can't even prove itself** obviously is not working for me. It's not like I'm unhappy doing and resisting what the religion says. I'm totally fine doing WHATEVER god asks me to do. It's just that it should be true. Not stories from other people. How can I be absolutely sure and doubtless about Islam? Is that even possible? You Muslims who have no problem with your beliefs, what is it that you know that I don't?

Again, I have no problem in completely doing whatever God's religion says. It's just that I should at least know if it really is true. Just like everyone else in the world.

Comment: About the hadith, there are well made ways of passing them from one person(muhadith - one who memorises hadith) to another in a well documented manner, which is rigorously tested graded and classified. Like Sahih hadith. So is the case with Quran.

Comment: @yawar You see there's the problem, neither I nor you have experienced the events the ahadith state. My question was asking for a proof that WE could use as basis for our belief. But we seemingly (at least as far as my extremely limited knowledge is concerned) have none. Us people living right now, we have just HEARD about the miracles of our prophet (saw). Of course if we could be 100% sure that the ahadith are true, and not manmade, this question would have never come up. But we aren't sure about them. That's not to say that they are false. They might be true, but we just don't know.

Comment: And how can I sacrifice so much of my life for something that I "don't know" about?

Comment: According to your logic you should also reject about anything people might say like anything which is said in history, but any historical proof can only be based on what has been left from that time: like books, letters, where you may find statement of people of the time, yes you could reject them as some information might be contradictory. So a bit of criticism is always good as Allah asks us to use our mind in many verses of the Quran. But on the other hand Islam is a belief, so here it's in first place your heart who should be addressed and the best evidence for that is your faith.

Comment: Here some helpful posts: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2383/why-did-god-send-prophets-only-to-arabia, http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/639/is-it-possible-that-the-quran-contains-any-errors, http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/779/are-there-any-miracles-in-the-holy-quran, http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16539/why-was-quran-revealed-in-arabic-language, http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-do-we-know-that-the-quran-has-never-been-changed, http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8079/how-can-we-trust-the-authenticity-of-the-koran-and-of-muhammad

Comment: @WaqarAnsari I'm really sad for what you're going through. After I read your question, it occurred to me that all four points you have made are examples of the same thing: miracle. I began to ask myself whether there is anything other than miracle that could attest to the validity of the Qur'an. I couldn't think of anything, so I posted the question here on SE. It seems no one else could think of anything. I think the closest you will get to the proof you're looking for is miracle. Or rather, as you have pointed out, the reports of miracle. Sorry for your difficulty.

Comment: Maybe this is a bit off-topic, but I think it could be helpful: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/139/should-i-force-myself-to-do-a-thing-which-my-mind-does-not-believe

Comment: you have answered yourself: "and of course, 4) the scientific miracles (let's not get into that)."

Comment: why "(let's not get into that)"?! you should not write such important thing in parentheses and without explanation. how do you understand the term "scientific miracle"?

Comment: duplicate of https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24463/what-is-the-proof-that-islam-is-the-truth-how-can-i-have-100-certainty

Comment: It seems what you are searching for is a strong evidence which is scientific one and you're refusing it without any specific reason (at least the is no reason for that in your post). There are many proof which you're searching for in Quran. A simple example is in surah Al-'Ankabut in which feminine verb (you should know Arabic to understand that) is used for the spider creating the web. Is it possible for a human to recognize that female spiders are ones who create web in 1400 years ago? Seeking for a good evidence for Islam is not easy and it seems you want it to be easy.

Comment: Errr, male spiders produce webs as well.  Its just female spiders need more food when are going to have young so they need and make better webs than males.  Male spiders make reasonable webs when they are growing up and need more food to grow.

Answer (score 2):

@WaqarAnsari, I get the point, the thing is how do I trust something that I haven't seen. You haven't seen me, nor I you, but if I tell you that I trust you to say the truth here regarding what you did yesterday. You may be honest or lie to me, I won't know either way, but I said I trust you to be honest. It is something that is natural in humans, but if you were with me and if you lied, I will know right away. The passing of ahadith and Quran is based on a rigourous method, where the chain of narrators of a single hadith is traced back to prophet Muhummad sallallahu alayhi wasalam, The personality of each link in the chain is verified (for honesty or crimes committed - a full fledged background check, deep into charechter and personal life). Also the hadith is tallied from multiple chains(if available) or verified from multiple sources. It is all trust based. Same is the case with Quran, there are Old scripts of Quran and new ones, the only way for Quran to remain corruption free is to see if old and new script tallies. How do we know the old scripture is genuine. Well it tallies with what was passed orally from prophet Muhummad sallallahu alayhi wasalam from that time till now. Through thousands of chains. And all tally with each other over such a long duration of time. It is possible only when all are correct and retrieve the integrity of text. This is all logic based. Now let's say someone who is in the chain forgets to pass a simple detail in hadith or a verse in Quran to the next link in due course of time. The next link will have to go through a exam(compulsory even today ) which is a really difficult (I mean it) exam to be qualified as a good link before being added to the chain of narrators. If you would like to see this process in action. I would suggest to visit an Islamic university (not school or 'madrasa') to see how this process happens (The most famous being Al-Azhar university in Cairo, Egypt). The one who qualifies it is awarded a degree similar to     other university degrees like undergrad (say memorising Quran in Arabic) and post-grad( say memorising Quran in Arabic with understanding of it's meaning and 'tafsir' or interpretation in any language(s)) or PhD (writing your own interpretation or likewise).

How can I be sure that miracles happened. if mentioned in hadith which are graded as 'Sahih'(confirmed good and strong narrator chain and verified integrity, by the best of scholars in multiple ages till now from multiple places on earth), then you are 100% sure it did happen. If graded 'daef', (some doubt's regarding some links in the chain, or doubt regarding integrity), the chances of it being correct are more than 60-80% because they are kept there despite some doubts, then there are those hadith which don't qualify the tests (They are most likely wrong depending upon if it contains evidently wrong text or there are some missing links in narrator chain and some serious doubt's).

The best collection of Hadith is organised in Book's called the Six Cannonical books, Which contains Sahih Bukhari, Sahih Muslim, Tirmidhi, An'Nasai', Abu-Dawood,Ibn'- Majah. Sahih Bukhari being the best recommended even among the six followed by Sahih Muslim and Tirmidhi (I don't remember the order of others). IT is all trust based

To convince yourself that you can trust the authenticity of what you hear from Quran and Hadith or even 'waqah'(narration of an event - althogh less common, not all waqah's are true, so remember that). It is best to meet a qualified muhadith and ask him narrate his chain of narrators up until him, and also ask him how this process works and evidently he would know more than me in regard.

Comment: That somewhat answers the Hadith part. But what about my main question? What are the clear proofs FOR US? We surely aren't supposed to just take their words are we? I mean their methodology might be very good and all, but are we just supposed to 'trust' them without knowing anything for ourselves?

Comment: That way, I might even trust hindu scriptures (if I could rationalize them to myself). I ofc wouldn't have proofs for them, but Islam isn't giving any to me either right? (Please tell if I'm right or wrong)

Comment: I kind of get what is rooting your confusion. you are confused about what to trust. But trust is an inherent thing in a person. Quran describes events and happenings, to teach us things and hold a lot of wisdom. Now the thing is whether you trust it or not. I trust it because I trust the sources. I trust sources because I know the verification process is too rigorous and the people involved are majorly (if not all) honest. Trust is the very basis of faith.

Comment: So Islam doesn't have any proofs and is trust based only? Meaning you just gotta have faith on what you hear and read about the prophet (saw)?

Comment: نْ نَشَأْ نُنَزِّلْ عَلَيْهِمْ مِنَ السَّمَاءِ آيَةً فَظَلَّتْ أَعْنَاقُهُمْ لَهَا خَاضِعِين      َ

If  We  willed,  We  could  send  down  to  them  from  the  sky  a  sign  for  which  their  necks would  remain  humbled.

Comment: @WaqarAnsari, that is the problem, you see. you are trying to relate every thing together without a good base. What alternative do you suggest that Allah should use to convince us humans. And what kind of proofs do you want, proof for what, why gravity exists?, why we were created?, why is everything the way it is?. In that manner you shouldn't even trust yourself, for what your eyes see is different than what your brain percieves, or not trust a vendor, who might hand you down a fake note.

Comment: If you go to the root of all questions above, you'll reach a point where it's absurd for things to exist by themselves unless there is someone managing it, 'God', In Islam we say 'Allah'.

Comment: And yes, you just got to have faith in what you hear (provided that the source is trustworthy and acknowledged by other and majority of muslims)

Comment: @yawar What do you mean by "trying to relate everything without a good base"? What would a good base be like? I'm sorry but that made no sense to me. I don't have any suggestions for an alternative that God should use and I don't have to either. That's out of this question. "And what kind of proof do you want, proof for what, why gravity exists?", I think I made that very clear in my question about what needed to be proved. "why gravity exists?", that again is out of the question.

Comment: I simply asked why there was nothing for us to base our faith on. You know, the only thing keeping me from asking that girl out next to me in class is Islam. If there's no evidence of the religion being true except texts that might or might not be true, why not follow Hinduism, Buddhism, or be an Atheist?

Comment: "In that manner you shouldn't even trust yourself, for what your eyes see is different than what your brain percieves, or not trust a vendor, who might hand you down a fake note", See, if a person says that the earth is round, his claim can be doubted and questioned by anyone, but when he gives evidence for it (which we have, no need to get into the details) his claim is true. Similarly, if I say Islam is God's religion, I need to have evidence for my claim.

Comment: When atheists claim that there's no god, their claim can be rejected for two reasons. 1) they have no proof for their claim, 2) there's evidence AGAINST their claim, which is obviously this amazing reality. Islam doesn't have anything disproving it, but there isn't anything proving it either. At least as far as my knowledge is concerned.

Comment: Sorry if my words seemed rude (I wasn't and didn't intend to). I now think that what you are simply, asking is 'proof that you can see and today in this century'. Quran is in arabic sure, if you want to see the linguistic miracle learn arabic fluently (nothing comes without hardwork). About the prophecies, you weren't there to see or hear them being said, but in due time you will see them being fulfilled (the prophecy of false prophets, a lot of which (those who claim without anything to back themselves with) have come forth in history already) this is the one most fresh in my mind.

Comment: and by my opinion satan is also quite evidently a clear proof (for muslims and all the good people  (why and how? - because according to his wish he'll till qiyamah do best to set us  astray from what is right using a simple thing called waswasa (In modern psychology - deviative thoughts, they arise unconditionaly out of nowhere and are processes by front or logical part of brain and audio processors and have a good amount of influence on brain IF, the persons thought process isn't structured and organised . They often if not always are not something a persons consious would agree with))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42617/discussion-between-yawar-and-waqar-ansari).